# What happens if the load on the electrical generator exceeds its generation power? And why?

Tags: electric-circuits, power, induction, electrical-engineering

What happens if the load on the electrical generator exceeds its power generation? and why?

To be more precise, suppose we have a standard induction generator operating at frequency $\nu=50\:\mathrm{Hz}$ and voltage $V_0$, and rated to produce a maximum power $P_0$, and that we connect this to a load $R<V_0^2/P_0$, which will try to draw more power than the generator's capacity. Obviously the details will depend on the type of generator, but, generally speaking: what will be the generator's response, and what physical processes are involved?

Answer (score 4):

As the current drawn by the load increases the torque opposing the motion of the prime mover on its coils increase. This opposing torque is a result of the force acting on the coil since it's a current carrying conductor moving in a magnetic field. Hence its rpm reduces and so does its voltage output.

Answer (score 3):

The generator circuit breaker should trip to avoid damage.  But if that doesn't work, or doesn't exist, the generator will not be able to maintain its speed.  On a typical AC system, this will cause the frequency to drop from the standard 50 or 60 Hz, as well as drop the output voltage.

Answer (score 2):

If the generator's power source exceeds the generator's capacity, and if a load is placed on the generator that also exceeds the generator's capacity, and if all safety devices are disabled; the generator would heated up to a point where the weakest link would burn out like a fuse and thus remove the electrical load.

Answer (score 0):

just decelerates and finally stops because of heat-induced physical deformations; because the load is always against the power of the engine. The engine always has limited work ability because of limited energy and so power.